# Visual Studio mac - issues with automatically signing iOS apps

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, info.plist, visual-studio-mac

I am using visual studio mac and xamarin forms. I am trying to debug an app on my iphone but have challenges. I get the following error message: "No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing identities." When I open info.plist, I cannot activate "Automatically manage signing" because the Team drop-down box is empty. I have already entered my apple developer account via the preferences-->Publishing-->Apple Developer Accounts.

Please help me to find what I have missed.

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

See [Set Up Device for Development](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/) and [Launching your App](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/free-provisioning/#Launching_your_App):

*"2. Open Xcode and browse to Xcode > Preferences.*

*3. Under Accounts, use the + button to add your existing Apple ID."*